# Pendrive install asks for CD

Tags: installation, usb, usb-drive

Trying to install from USB on a Win 8 machine. It boots from the Pendrive USB fine, but when the dialogue gets past the language and keyboard select, it asks for the CD and won't go any further. How can I get around this? Trying to install server 12.04. Thanks!

Comment: How did you create the USB?

Comment: With the Pendrive USB installer from pendrivelinux.com following their instructions after downloading the .iso from the Ubuntu site.

Answer (score 0):

Try [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).  I have had some problems with  Pendrive USB installer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Created a USB and tried it with the exact same result. Is there something in the install file that causes it to look for a CD? Also, the error says that "The CD ROM drive contains a CD which cannot be used for the install" There is no CD in the drive.

Comment: Try to verify the ISO file by doing an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Comment: Still not sure what the problem was, but I was able to select 'expert install' from the menu that popped up using UNetbootin and was able to use a mirror to install Ubuntu. Thanks to all that responded!